# How can I understand if two lithium ion battery types are exchangable or not?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion

I am kind of beginner about electronics and I want to understand how can I compare two different model of the same kind (lithium-ion) batteries?

I would like to understand this because I sent my robot vacuum to warranty and they exchanged the original battery (Hu Nan Giantsun power, 18650 4S1P (4INR19/66)) with another brand (in fact white label pack of 4x 18650BD) and I want to be sure they are compatible because of fire safety etc. and I would like to learn how to compare batteries.

Here is my original battery

[image: Original battery came with the robot vacuum]

And they changed it with NCR18650BD pack (white label but these codes can be seen under white plastic cover). It seems they manufactured by Panasonic but there is Panasonic label on them, is that possible or are they fake/non-Panasonic?) They look like this;

[image]

[image]

First difference is, new batteries are 3200 mAh batteries, what can it change? Duration of power? And the specs I've found on internet shows these data but I need help to correctly interpret and compare.

[image]

And it seems both of the battery packs has some small circuit under/top of them. What it does? Does it have any affect on charging/protection or just simple connection circuit?

And how can I be sure about the safety of using these new batteries?

Comment: If it's a warranty repair, it's highly likely to be a suitable part.

Comment: @BrianDrummond you're right for the most but unfortunately it may not be in the country I live.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the replacement battery.
The higher mAh battery will take longer to charge and have a longer discharge time.
The datasheet for the battery cell will say if it has protection circuit.

Comment: unfortunately only the datasheet I can find is NCR18650BD datasheet because the battery pack doesn't have any label/sign etc. on it. So I cannot validate what kind of protection circuit it has or what are the specs.